# Adding selection to Bundle Quote Item programmatically

Tags: event-observer, quote, bundle-product

**Summary**

I created a module in which I'm able to add configurable items whithin Bundles to cart. The product view is working fine and i managed it to add the products to the cart. The problem is that the simple configurated child product of the configurable parent is missing in the cart, and i need it beacause of stock managment.

I suspect that the reason is that the simple product is not added to the selection array of the bundle item. The child data is in the custom options of the configurable product. My approach will be to access the bundle item through an observer pull out the data of the configurable child product and add it to the bundle selections programmatically.

This is what i did so far. Through an event i catch the data before adding the products to the Quote:

```
<events>
        <sales_quote_add_item> 
            <observers>
                <configurablebundleset>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>MyCompany_ConfigurableBundleSet_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>salesQuoteEditItems</method>
                </configurablebundleset>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_add_item>
    </events>
```

then in the observer i have:

```
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $item = $event->getQuoteItem();
    $product = $item->getProduct();

    $infoBuyRequest = $item->getBuyRequest()->toArray();
    $bundleROption = $infoBuyRequest['bundle_option'];

        /**
     * @var Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Type
     */
    $typeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance(true);

    // get bundle options
    $optionsQuoteItemOption =  $item->getOptionByCode('bundle_option_ids');


    $bundleOptionsIds = unserialize($optionsQuoteItemOption->getValue());

    if ($bundleOptionsIds)
    {
        /**
         * @var Mage_Bundle_Model_Mysql4_Option_Collection
         */
        `Here i want to pass the bundle Selection of the buy_request`
        $optionsCollection = $typeInstance->getOptionsByIds($bundleROption, $item);

        // get and add bundle selections collection
        $selectionsQuoteItemOption = $item->getOptionByCode('bundle_selection_ids');

//            print_r($selectionsQuoteItemOption->getValue()); die;

        $selectionsCollection = $typeInstance->getSelectionsByIds(
            unserialize($selectionsQuoteItemOption->getValue()),
            $product
        );

//            print_r($optionsCollection);
//            $optionsCollection->appendSelections($selections, false, $_appendAllSelections);


        $bundleOptions = $optionsCollection->appendSelections($selectionsCollection, true);


        foreach ($bundleOptions as $bundleOption)
        {
            print_r($bundleOption);

            if ($bundleOption->getSelections())
            {
                $label = $bundleOption->getTitle();

                print_r($label);

                $bundleSelections = $bundleOption->getSelections();

                foreach ($bundleSelections as $bundleSelection)
                {
                    print_r($bundleSelection->getName());
                }

                // some more code here to do stuff

            }
        }
    }
    die;
```

Unfortunately the foreach loop is not working, the $bundleOptions is empty. In the $bundleSelections i want to inject the data like so:

```
                        if($simple = $bundleSelection->getOptionByCode('simple_product'))
                    {
//                        Mage::log('Selection test: '.print_r($selection->setSku('asdfasdf'), true), null, 'type.log');
                        $simpleId = $simple->getProduct()->getId();
                        Mage::log('Simple Id: '.print_r($simpleId, true), null, 'type.log');
                        $item = array(
                            "option_id"=> '30',
                            "parent_product_id" => '167',
                            "product_id" => '129',
                            "position" => '0',
                            "is_default " => '0',
                            "selection_price_type" => '0',
                            "selection_price_value" => '0',
                            "selection_qty" =>'1',
                            "selection_can_change_qty" => '1'
                        );
                        $selection->setData($item);
                        $selection->save();


                    }
```

I need the proper way of inserting the simple child product into the bundle object before adding it to cart. I did a lot of research but there is no documentation of this, just a few posts of how you can create an bundle programmatically and how to access the bundle data.

Until now, however, my code is not working and i can't access the selections through the code above. It will be nice if you guys can point me in the right direction.

Also is the question in which way to access generally the data of a configured bundle object which will be added to the quote.